# so have written this code that opens webcam for video and i want to save the logs of when the cam was turned on but the file doesn't stop updating

Tags: python, file, opencv

so i am new to python but i wanted to open the webcam using cv2 and i was also trying to save the logs like when the webcam was opened so am using a file.txt to store, so i use the datetime and save it into the file.txt but the issue is that the file doesn't stop updating until i close the program. Kindly help

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import cv2
import datetime

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('app.html')

@app.route("/calculate", methods=['POST'])
def webcam():
    import cv2

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # Check if the webcam is opened correctly
    if not cap.isOpened():
        raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

    while True:
        
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=1, fy=1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        

        # describe the type of font
        # to be used.
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        
        #writing text
        cv2.putText(frame, "Press esc to quit", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (199,21,133))
        
        cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
        
        #storing logs in a file
        with open("logs.txt",'w') as myfile:
            ct=datetime.datetime.now()
            myfile.write(str(ct))
             
        
        c = cv2.waitKey(1) #add 0 for frame pic when you stroke any key
        if c == 27:
            break
        
            
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return render_template("app.html")
```

Comment: Do some research on flushing your output stream to disk.

Comment: i shall do more research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from where you are logging... When you put the logging code under the `while True` statement, it will keep logging until the loop is interrupted.

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` I guess this line is the one opening the webcam because after that you are checking if the webcam was opened successfully... Why not move the logging code after like

```py
# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

#storing logs in a file
with open("logs.txt",'w') as myfile:
    ct=datetime.datetime.now()
    myfile.write(str(ct))
```